# Azure SQL Database Deployment task

Tags: azure-devops

We have a set of Azure SQL Database Deployment tasks set up in Azure Devops, deploy type SQL DACPAC File using Hosted VS2017. Most pass however some result in error:

```
2019-04-04T23:51:59.1581965Z Initializing deployment (Start)
2019-04-04T23:52:26.0452995Z Initializing deployment (Complete)
2019-04-04T23:52:26.0453268Z Analyzing deployment plan (Start)
2019-04-04T23:52:26.1340183Z Analyzing deployment plan (Complete)
2019-04-04T23:52:26.1346216Z Updating database (Start)
2019-04-04T23:52:31.2433080Z Creating Name...
2019-04-04T23:52:37.8176073Z Updating database (Failed)
2019-04-04T23:52:37.9828381Z ##[error]*** Could not deploy package.
2019-04-04T23:52:37.9918864Z ##[error]Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 42019, Level 16, State 4, Line 1 CREATE DATABASE operation failed. Internal service error.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE DATABASE [$(D
2019-04-04T23:52:38.0103747Z ##[error]atabaseName)] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;


Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0 A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
```

Each of these tasks utilise the same:

- Authentication Type
- Azure SQL Server
- Login
- Password
- Firewall set IPAddressRange 0.0.0.0 / 255.255.255.255

Not sure why this is occurring when the same login details are used and deploys to some but not others.

We have deployed the dacpac locally and works with no issues.

Any ideas as to why this is occurring?

Comment: What parameters are you providing to the task?

Comment: I am using the required parameters listed here
[link](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/SqlAzureDacpacDeploymentV1/README.md)

Azure Connection Type
Azure Subscription
Azure SQL server Name
Database Name
SQL Username
SQL Password
Deployment package type (DACPAC file)

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify: What **values** are you providing?

Comment: Values have been set as per pipeline variables in the release e.g. Azure SQL Server $(Database.Server.Name).database.windows.net where $Database.Server.Name equals to oneseek-seek-data; Login $(Database.AdminLogin) where $Database.AdminLogin equals oneseeuser. Not sure why this is failing as other tasks deploying database dacpac files have no issues deploying.